# Create RSA public key from JSON response

Tags: api, jwt, rsa, response

I need join response data to RSA public key in PEM format

I receive a response with JWS and in the second query the RSA key to verify them. The key data is split. How to combine them so that you can verify the signature, e.g. at jwt.io

Example response:

```
b'{"keys":[{"kty":"RSA","kid":"VLYrH06rhWXATN7ogs0ykjlHSWYNy-KwuOcvXvr_pQo","use":"sig","n":"jdLLhDWIRAAKOZ09L7eiYPmfzKw5sQ5vWENJR' 

b'BSaHUJ5G0QWG5UZ7-PvAAtfX1ZLKTgujt2iJ7Ucl_XcVLcOsC7APp0ipu2NECPqy6aSlSdAL9J_luley_p2Vea6_O-DRMtBO7Ec7ha9U5HKijmWhaCzLQT3joK1s7-2q' 

b'I6a2BDxZQT1ZUZLcavQyXe5Atfj1ltTxSCmDuV_nvAdyY3DBeYDxlidWozkdvh6m9CuALh9c8XQjq6vhdno6TDqUtsh4yCNjwle9WAAukGC-gSibB9_a9qRlK_T6uhkD' 

b'MUNOxpSwA4CTwTKMK_pWf5u2tJ_4QVlr_XLoFZaBhHn4FTT0w","e":"AQAB"}]}'
```